# Изменить массив numpy построчно

Tags: python, numpy

Дан массив А = ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]) и одномерные массивы b = ([19, 2, 63]), c = ([74, 58, 76]), d = ([71, 28, 93]).
Как первую строку массива А заменить на массив b, вторую строку заменить на массив с, а третью на массив d?

Comment: A = np.array([b, c, d])

Comment: Большое спасибо!